# UILocalNotification repeatInterval

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have 2 questions.

1. If I understand local notifications the repeatinterval allows me to have a notification scheduled once and it repeated on the same interval each week or month or day of week.  I am trying to get a repeatinterval to fire once on say a Tuesday and each week it will fire again on the same day i.e. Tuesday.  This should go on every week without needing to schedule another notification.  Is that correct.  Is is not happening.  I am either doing something wrong in code or I am testing it wrong.
2. In the simulator I run the app schedule the notificaiton.  The notification comes up which I view.  Then I quit the app and set the system date to 1 week in the future same day of week but no notification so can I test this notification this way by changing the computers system clock.  I do not want to have to wait a week for each test.

Here is the code

```
- (void) scheduleNotificationWithItem:(NSDate *)date interval:(int)frequency {
 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

 if (localNotif == nil) {
      return;
 }

 localNotif.fireDate = [date addTimeInterval:frequency];
 localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
 localNotif.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
 localNotif.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitWeekday;
 localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
 localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@.",nil),@"Weekly Reminder"];
 localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Notification Details", nil);
 localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

 [localNotif release];
}
```

Please help this is driving me crazy.
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 6):

1) Setting your repeat interval to 'NSWeekCalendarUnit' should do the trick. It repeats on a weekly basis on the same day and time as the original notification.

2) I haven't tested in the simulator but changing the clock on an actual iPhone does fire future alerts.

Comment: for #2, it works in the simulator if you change the system clock on whatever you're running the simulator on (Macbook or other Macs [or Hackintosh]). I've tested this on 5.1 simulator and 6.0 simulator...